# UIAlertController freezes in Swift 5 when using addTextField (target iOS12.4) - Transitioning from Objective C

Tags: swift, migration, uitextfield, uialertcontroller

My Swift view controller is called from my mainly Objective C app.  Calling function 'showAlert()' displays, but freezes the emulator.  I get no error, but none of the buttons work and the textfield doesn't raise the keyboard (the placeholder shows up). (My actual code has more alertActions, which work fine if I comment out the TextField code). I even copied verbatim code from StackOverflow to display a basic alert controller with a TextField, and it has the same issue as written below.

```
@objc class MyVC :UIViewController {

@objc func showAlert() {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addTextField { (textField : UITextField!) -> Void in
            textField.placeholder = "Enter name"
        }

        let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm", style: .default, handler: { alert -> Void in
            if let textField = alertController.textFields?[0] {
                if textField.text!.count > 0 {
                    print("Text :: \(textField.text ?? "")")
                }
            }
        })

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: {
            (action : UIAlertAction!) -> Void in })

        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        alertController.addAction(saveAction)

        alertController.preferredAction = saveAction

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

A breakpoint at 'present(...' show the alert controller allocated, but stepping in from here ends with the frozen display of the alertcontroller. Any debug suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: That worked!  However, I cannot see the change.  Even Xcode compare can't see it - please tell me which characters you changed - and THANK YOU SO MUCH!